# mplotlib plot on mac displays once then does not display

Tags: python

I have tried many answers given here to similar looking problem but none worked so far. I am using following code to display plot. Plot displays ok first time but if I display again with modification to code, it does not display again for a long time.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(stepsTaken, meanDistances)
plt.title("mean distance from origin")
plt.xlabel("steps taken")
plt.ylabel("steps from origin")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you mean, "*without* modification to the code"?

Comment: actually, it does not matter. I am trying with or without modification of the code. the plot does not show again.

Comment: I am using matplotlib (1.4.3)

Comment: @yogen: pls provide more details, i.e. whether you are using iPython console or something like that

Comment: I am not using ipython. I am using python 2.7 in virtual env. I have tried to run example from python console (REPL) as well as pycharm community edition, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do "plt.figure()" before defining every instance of the plot, the same as in the tutorial: http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/intro_matplotlib.html